# Google Sheets Scatter chart: multiple data points at same X location

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have a dataset where I have on each row data associated with an item that has a name (alpha, beta, gamma in the example), as follows:

[image: Dataset example]

I now want to create a scatter plot where the `X` axis corresponds to the names (alpha, beta, gamma) and the `Y` axis corresponds to the values in `v1`. But I want to only have one entry of alpha, beta, gamma on the `X` axis, respectively.

This happens automatically if the `X` axis values are numbers, but I can't figure out how to do it if they are strings.

I don't want to have to assign each name a number and then modify the x-axis to show these names at the given numbers because the dataset is quite large.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Here you go https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QbTeCIp_uH3MNproRrhl782vdwju4XBfXmb3Af3D_qU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

If your x-axis is numerical, it works. Rename "alpha", "beta", "gamma" to 1, 2, 3 respectively, to make the dots be on top of each other. See [test file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mkuxVn-Z_Y_mWymjkVEgMz6p5iVDT9ECdi2fzy-uW-w/preview)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You will need to **Aggregate** them under **Median**, **Average**, **Sum**, **Max** or **Min** like:

[image: 0]

Comment: There is no way to have multiple dots for `v1` on top of each other?

Comment: @Nicolas nope, the aggregation is the only way

Comment: Aggregation fundamentally changes the data, it is not a solution for this whatsoever.  If Sheets simply won't collapse non-numeric labels and align the data points vertically instead of staggering them, then the "only way" is to use another product.